# Creating a Dictionary with a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

Trying to assign a number to each letter within the string abc. Instead of getting a dictionary of {a : 0, b : 1, c : 2 etc} i get many new lines with only one key pair.

```
message = "54 396 131 198 225 258 87 258 128 211 57 235 114 258 144 220 39 175 330 338 297 288"
m2 = message.replace(" ", ",")
print(m2)
li = list(m2.split(","))
print(li)
res = []
#res = [eval(i) for i in li]
for i in li:
    res.append(eval(i))
    
print(res)
giz = []
for i in res:
    giz.append(i % 37)

print(giz)


#for i in f:
#   print(int(math.fmod(i, 37)),end=" ")
abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_"

d = {}
o = -1
for i in abc:
    o += 1
    d = {o : i}
    
    print(d)
```

output

```
54,396,131,198,225,258,87,258,128,211,57,235,114,258,144,220,39,175,330,338,297,288
['54', '396', '131', '198', '225', '258', '87', '258', '128', '211', '57', '235', '114', '258', '144', '220', '39', '175', '330', '338', '297', '288']
[54, 396, 131, 198, 225, 258, 87, 258, 128, 211, 57, 235, 114, 258, 144, 220, 39, 175, 330, 338, 297, 288]
[17, 26, 20, 13, 3, 36, 13, 36, 17, 26, 20, 13, 3, 36, 33, 35, 2, 27, 34, 5, 1, 29]
{0: 'a'}
{1: 'b'}
{2: 'c'}
{3: 'd'}
{4: 'e'}
{5: 'f'}
{6: 'g'}
{7: 'h'}
{8: 'i'}
{9: 'j'}
{10: 'k'}
{11: 'l'}
{12: 'm'}
{13: 'n'}
{14: 'o'}
{15: 'p'}
{16: 'q'}
{17: 'r'}
{18: 's'}
{19: 't'}
{20: 'u'}
{21: 'v'}
{22: 'w'}
{23: 'x'}
{24: 'y'}
{25: 'z'}
{26: '0'}
{27: '1'}
{28: '2'}
{29: '3'}
{30: '4'}
{31: '5'}
{32: '6'}
{33: '7'}
{34: '8'}
{35: '9'}
{36: '_'}
```

I tried looking on google and everywhere and couldn't find the answer. Any advice on finding answers to obscure questions like this for the future?

Comment: In every iteration you are creating a new dictionary and print it. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: A couple observations:  (1) Change `li = list(m2.split(","))` to `li = m2.split(",")`.  It's *already* a list.  Don't obfuscate your code.  (2) Your loop is way off.  For one thing, what do you think `d = {o : i}` does?  Do you think it changes the existing dict?  It doesn't.  It creates a new dict with a single entry, then saves it in `d`, discarding the old dict.  That should be very clear:  You're assigning to `d`.  That's what assignment does.  There are additional logic problems with the loop, but you should start by understanding what the code you wrote actually does.

Comment: I wanted it to keep adding them to the dictionary so I had multiple key-values in the dictionary. I saw .update as way way to add new key-values, but it didn't work it just did the same thing

Comment: @TomKarzes ... (3) Don't use `eval` to convert `str` to `int`. Use `int(...)`

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes, good point.  There are lots of problems with the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are printing the dictionary in each iteration of the loop
Second, you should use the update method because you are redefining the dictionary every iteration instead of adding to it.
it should look like

```
d = {}
o = 0
for i in abc:
    d.update({o : i})
    o+=1
print(d)
```

Comment: creating a new dict every iteration is a waste of time and memory. Just do `d[o] = i`

Comment: And can use `enumerate` instead of manually keeping track of `o`.

Comment: Why would you use `d.update({o : i})`?  That's just a very bad way of doing `d[o] = i`.  Don't fight the language.

Answer (score 0):

```
abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_"

d = {}
o = 1
for i in abc:
    d[i] = o
    o+=1

print(d)
```

Comment: No need for the loop. Just `dict(enumerate(abc))` or `dict(enumerate(abc, 1))` if the indexes should start at 1 and not 0.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is use dict.update({...}) function --> to answer your basic question. it writes to an existing dict without creating a new one.

To simplify the whole thing I would suggest using

```
message = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"
resultingDict = dict([(int(c), chr(int(c)+97)) for c in message.split(' ')])
print (resultingDict)
```

to generate the output of

```
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j', 10: 'k'}
```

Good luck

Comment: Why? OP already has the input string. All they really want is `dict((index, ch) for index, ch in enumerate(abc))`

Comment: I suggested dict.update, which is, maybe not the most efficient, still a valid solution to OPs basic question.

Comment: It can even just be `dict(enumerate(abc))` as a matter of fact

Comment: **Moderator Note:** I've deleted a bunch of comments here discussing and/or complaining about downvotes. Voting is anonymous on this platform by design. No one is ever expected to give an explanation or reason for their downvote. The explanation for what a downvote means is given in the tooltip for the downvote arrow. (It is precisely the opposite of what an upvote means.) Do not leave any more comments discussing or whining about downvotes, here or anywhere on Stack Overflow.